# Echoing data from the database to the option in select box together with the choices

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have select box with some options if the user select something it will be recorded into the database and I want to echo out the selected data into the same select box together with options.

here's the select box

```
    <div class="input-group">
  <label>College</label>
  <select id="College" name="College">
        <option value="">---Select College---</option>
        <option value="College of Arts and Sciences">College of Arts and Sciences</option>
        <option value="College of Business Administration">College of Business Administration</option>
        <option value="College of Industrial Technology">College of Industrial Technology</option>
        <option value="College of Nursing, Pharmacy and Allied Health Sciences">College of Nursing, Pharmacy and Allied Health Sciences</option>
        <option value="EDUCATION">EDUCATION</option>
      </select>
```

So if I choose education then it will be recorded to the userinfo table under college. So if the user search student the system will echo out the user's information that includes the education data under college row..but if I search student the select box will show the first option which is the select college not the education which the user choose and it's recorded in the database. If the user choose to search for the user info it will show all the recorded information in the same textbox or select box where you input the information but if i click update it always show the first choice not the option that is recorded in the database. Thanks in advance

Comment: Query, it is missing the query. You must to check if value is the same stored in database and add selected in option if is true

Comment: how should i do that sir?